# Mongoose saves are not showing in shell

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a simple Express server: [Gist](https://gist.github.com/MrOnlineCoder/fa0155a560d76300413f)

When I start server, meow appears in log, and if I go to /cats route, I receive JSON of Silence kitten. But when I try **db.test.find()** in MongoDB shell, I get nothing. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. I should use **db.kittens.find()** instead of **db.test.find()**